# Blur part of image in PAINT.NET

Tags: layers, paint.net, layer-style

I have a simple problem. I have an image with text (as image). I want to blur this text. I think I did it before but it is not working the way I am doing.

> Create a new layer, draw a rectangle on this layer which covers the
>   area I need to blur. I added blur effect to the this rectangle.

It did not work. I tried putting some color to this rectangle, tried different blend option for the layer but nothing worked.

What is the easier way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it myself but will accept any answer that is better

> Make sure the edit you are working in is in top layer. If not bring it
>   all the way to top. Work in the same layer, draw a rectangle selection
>   on area you want to create blur Go to Menu > Effects > Blurs >
>   Gaussian Blur and set the amount.

Your selected area will not be blurred. If you moved your based later to the top, now you can move it back to base layer. The effects will appear.

Note: The above does not work if your image is not int the top layer.

Comment: I don't have the rep to post this as an answer just yet, but all I had to do was use the selection tool to select the area that I wanted to blur, then apply the Gaussian Blur effect. I did not have to create any extra layers, or rectangles, etc.